# How do I troubleshoot a white MacBook that won't boot?

Tags: macbook-pro, startup

I was given an older MacBook ([MacBook 2,1, Late 2006, A1181](http://everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook/specs/macbook-core-2-duo-2.0-white-13-specs.html)) that won't boot. I can't figure out why. When I push the power button, the CD drive spins, like usual, and the white power light on the front comes on, but the screen never comes on and the boot chime never happens.
I was able to get it to boot last night by holding <kbd>Left Shift</kbd>, <kbd>Command</kbd>, <kbd>Option</kbd> and <kbd>Power Button</kbd> (resets the SMC) and it was fine, and I proceeded to wipe the HDD and reinstall OS X, but it won't boot again this morning. Thoughts? I followed all of [Apple's suggestions](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS1367?viewlocale=en_US) again, but they didn't work.

Comment: Hve you made a bootable usb dongle? Try to boot with that. Most probably your HDD drive is the problem.

Comment: @FeliceM It booted fine, and I can take the HDD out and connect it via USB just fine. Could the HDD still be the problem?

Comment: I had the same problem on my wife MB. The problem was very very similar. I battled for weeks to make it booting. Sometime was booting and sometime not until the HDD crashed completely. After replacing it and restoring the backup from TM, I never heard new complains from the wife. So, in my case the problem was the HDD informing us that was close to die.